# What do I need for a callback API service to connect to my server via SSL?

Tags: php, api, ssl, https

I need to use an API that passes information to a callback script on my server.

The API connects using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).  I've never worked with SSL and I don't know if I need to get some kind of certificate to get it to work on my Server.

I'm using PHP and these are all the current settings related to SSL that I could find via phpinfo():

---

Registered Stream Socket Transports: `tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls`

SSL `Yes`

SSL Version  `OpenSSL/0.9.8b`

OpenSSL support `enabled`

OpenSSL Library Version `OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008`

OpenSSL Header Version  `OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008`

Native OpenSSL support  `enabled`

---

So what do I need to do in order for the API to connect to my server via SSL?

Also, will I have to use `https` in the URL of my callback script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your server to be accessed via SSL, you do need a certificate for it on your server.  While calling the other server, you would use the `https` to access it.  So if the API that you are calling requires a secure callback via SSL, then you do need the certificate.  Otherwise, you do not.